# Use DeleteView to delete an object, got "'mysite' is not a registered namespace"

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I followed this example to upload document to AWS (https://github.com/sibtc/simple-s3-setup/tree/master/s3-example-static-and-media). I am now adding a functionality which allows user to delete an uploaded document.

I got the error "django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'mysite' is not a registered namespace". Followed is the parameter values in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py: 
args    [1]; current_app    ''; current_ns  None; current_path  None; kwargs    {}; ns  'mysite'; ns_converters {}; ns_pattern  ''; parts   ['delete', 'mysite']; path  []; prefix  '/'; resolved_path  []; resolver    ; urlconf   'mysite.urls'; view 'delete'; viewname  'mysite:delete'

Here are the files I made changes: 
(1) mysite/core/views.py 
`class DocumentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Document
    fields = ['upload', ]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')`

```
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       documents = Document.objects.all()
       context['documents'] = documents
       return context
```

*(below was added by me.I may need to add some code here to make the deletion work)* 
`class DocumentDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Document
    fields = ['upload', ]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')`

```
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       documents = Document.objects.all()
       context['documents'] = documents
       return context
```

(2) mysite/urls.py 
`app_name = 'mysite'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.DocumentCreateView.as_view(), name='home'),
    *(below was added by me)*
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', views.DocumentDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
]`

(3) mysite/core/templates/core/document_form.html: 
I also added the following code to line 27 of 
https://github.com/sibtc/simple-s3-setup/blob/master/s3-example-static-and-media/mysite/core/templates/core/document_form.html 
`<td><a href="{% url 'mysite:delete' document.id %}">Delete</a></td>` 
(If I change 'mysite:delete' to 'delete', I got "Reverse for 'delete' not found. 'delete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.")

Comment: Since this is the root `urls` (I guess), you should use `{% url 'delete' document_id %}`.

Comment: Hi @Willem, as I mentioned in my post, if I use <td><a href="{% url 'delete' document.id %}">Delete</a></td>, I got "Reverse for 'delete' not found. 'delete' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Comment: remove the app_name = 'mysite' from the url and try

Comment: I have tried by removing "app_name = 'mysite' ", but got the same errors as reported in the question.